# IBM MFP Console Adapter Display

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In IBM MFP 8, Is there any way to increase the show count of adapters in MFP Console.

If the adapter count is more than 100, it is not showing in the adapters list.

Comment: Do you have more than 100 adapters? Is this some dev/test system?

Comment: Yes ! its DEV environment only

Comment: When you say that the adapter are not being shown in the adapter list, is that it's showing 100 adapters and 101 onwards it's not showing in the console? Or if the count of  adapter is more than 100, the console is not showing any adapters at all? and the console shows an error message? Can you try : GET --user admin:admin http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters and see if this call is returning all the adapters?

Comment: The curl command is : curl GET --user <adminUsername>:<adminPassword> http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters